# Software pattern to access MMIO in concurrent environment

Tags: c++, c, concurrency

I'm looking for a software pattern preferably in C/C++ how to safely access MMIO peripherals in microcontroller such as ARM Cortex-M in concurrent environment - interrupts and main/threads (in case of OS).

The root of the issue is that every peripheral has its registers declared as global variable(struct/class). That means anybody can access them (yes, there are features like MPU and MMU, but they are not the answer).

To limit their scope I'm looking for a software pattern. The closest is Singleton (though, it isn't the best for concurrent programming).

When I make the peripheral a Singleton I can sleep safe that no other part of the code will modify the it at least through the API offered by the peripheral.

However, this works till the point I need interrupts. At least on Cortex-M the interrupt is generated by the peripheral and signaled to the CPU through Nested Vector Interrupt Controller. The CPU stops executing current instruction and fetches the interrupt handler.

Inside the handler I need to set some bit in the peripheral in order to deactivate the interrupt source otherwise the interrupt would be still pending and after leaving I would execute it again and again.

Tough, thanks the Singleton pattern I can now create a deadlock as I might not get the access.

Is there a software pattern that could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your deliberations are wrong as you treat uC as computer with operating system where many programs can be run bu the users.

This is not the case here.

> That means anybody can access them

Who is that anybody? It is only your program nothing else. You wrote it. You mdify it. If you do not trust yourself to this level - better givup uC development. Even RTOS-es are not the same as big computer OSes. RTOS is a part of your application - compiled and linked together.

So do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yes, you're right. uC is not a computer. However, even on uC you can run multiple programs also in isolation with MPU though without the benefit of virtual space. However, that was not my question. My question is more about mutable global variable and how to solve access from multiple "threads"? You can think of the HW as a scheduler and you have no idea when a thread (meant as interrupt) will run. And I just want to make an API that will be able to cope with that.

Comment: You cant. If one thread will go out of the control (UB for example) and starts writing the addresses ocuppiued by the hardware registers - you cant do anything about it.

Comment: @phodina pseuso language constructs will not provide any safety of the running code. It is 100% pointless. BTW how are you going to `run multiple programs` on the Cortex M4?  OS is not the same as Windows or Linux. It is the part of your program.

Comment: You're right about one thread panicking and writing anywhere. I don't want to rewrite an RTOS as that would be pointless since I could use e.g. FreeRTOS. My point is about guarding global resource in a "sane" program. I guess the best practice would be to have some synchronization primitives e.g. mutexes and short "atomic" function which can't be preemted by interrupts.